# How to create the int 1 at two different memory locations?

Tags: python, cpython

I want to show someone how using `is` instead of `==` to compare integers can fail.  I thought this would work, but it didn't:

```
>>> import copy
>>> x = 1
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> x is y
True
```

I can do this easily for bigger integers:

```
>>> x = 500
>>> y = 500
>>> x is y
False
```

How can I demonstrate the same thing with smaller integers which might typically be used for enum-like purposes in python?

Comment: You can't, integers between -1 and 99 are interned on cPython

Comment: Download the source to Python and modify the code to create a version that doesn't intern ints

Comment: @PavelAnossov It's `-5` to `256`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/306353/956362 sheds some light on it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: that's hardly going to prove to someone who wants to use `is` that it can fail on an actual python installation.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: oops. Here's the relevant source: https://gist.github.com/anossov/8707420

Comment: @Wooble Given that -5 to 256 are interned, what other way do you have in mind?

Comment: Well, you can't prove that using `is` on small integers will fail, because you're trying to prove something that's false. If the person's too dumb to understand why you still shouldn't use it, you should just give up and hope you never have to maintain code they wrote.

Comment: @Wooble Indeed so. So if you want to make such integers not be interned, you have to change the code. My original comment was a light hearted attempt to point out the futility of the stated goal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following example fails in both Python 2 and 3:

```
>>> n=12345
>>> ((n**8)+1) % (n**4) is 1
False
>>> ((n**8)+1) % (n**4) == 1
True
```

The reasons are slightly different. Python 2 uses the `int` type for small integers and the `long` type for arbitrary precision values. Only the `int` type is interned so the example fails when a `1L` is returned.

Python 3 only uses the arbitrary precision type (and renamed it to `int`). The example fails because the remainder calculation internally computes a value of 1 and returns it. The interning check is only done when objects are created and the object was created at the start of the calculation before it had the value 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
>>> 0 - 6 is -6
False
>>> 0 - 6 == -6
True
```

It also works for bigger numbers:

```
>>> 1000 + 1 is 1001
False
>>> 1000 + 1 == 1001
True
```

It depends on what you want to demonstrate but the above highlights the difference in functionality between `is` and `==`.

Comment: I already know this.. I thought I was clear about asking about ints like 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

What you observe is expected:

```
>>> x=256
>>> y=256
>>> x is y
True
>>> x=257
>>> y=257
>>> x is y
False
>>> x=-5
>>> y=-5
>>> x is y
True
>>> x=-6
>>> y=-6
>>> x is y
False
```

Quoting from [Plain Integer Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all
>   integers between `-5` and `256`, when you create an int in that range you
>   actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it
>   should be possible to change the value of `1`. I suspect the behaviour
>   of Python in this case is undefined. :-)

Comment: Can I kick 1 out of the intern somehow?

Comment: @wim Hack the sources?