# Does float create different object instances each time we call them?

Tags: python

Could some explain this in detail:

```
print(float(5.3) is float(5.3))#True
print(float(5) is float(5))#False
print(int(5) is int(5))#True
```

The first one returns False and the second one returns True. So I would really be grateful if you guys could me what is happening behind the scenes.
Thanks in Advance:)

**EDIT**: Appreciate everyone's comments but I really do understand that the IDs are different in the 2nd case and the same in the 1st case. And obviously, it can be found out using id(). **But what I exactly want to know is whyyy the ID's are different?**

Comment: I guess a more correct way of checking if objects are equal: `print(id(float(5)) == id(float(5)))`, which gives `True`

Comment: `id(x) == id(y)` should always be equivalent to `x is y`. The results might vary across different versions or implementations of Python, though.

Comment: You aren't testing what you think you are here.  The two literals on the same line do not exist at the same time (they are eligible for garbage collection as soon as `float()` or `int()` is called), so you cannot distinguish between "two references to the same object" and "two separately-created objects that happened to get allocated at the same memory address".

Comment: Yes, good point.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you, Sir. Your answer looks very convincing. If you don't mind, I would be grateful if you could explain it to me in detail:). Like what you meant by garbage collection in this context. Thanks

Comment: @kaya3 Yes true. I was more interested on "why the ID's" it is different? My apology for not clear mentioning it in the question. I have updated it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the issue of whether two occurrences of the same literal are the same object (that's [an implementation detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62175978/is-0-is-0-always-true-in-python)), let's give our values names so that the same name always refers to the same object.

```py
>>> x = 5.3
>>> y = 5
```

We can see that in fact, when you call the `float` or `int` constructors on values which already are floats or ints respectively, they do not construct new objects, instead they return the original objects:

```py
>>> x is float(x)
True
>>> y is int(y)
True
```

So of course `float(x) is float(x)` will be `True`, because that's the same as writing `x is x`. Likewise for `int(y) is int(y)`. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) say *"For a general Python object `x`, `float(x)` delegates to `x.__float__()`"* and *"If `x` defines `__int__()`, `int(x)` returns `x.__int__()`"*, and it makes sense that `float.__float__` and `int.__int__` both just return the object itself.

However, when you call the `float` constructor multiple times on the same `int` value, you *are* constructing a new object each time:

```py
>>> y1 = float(y)
>>> y2 = float(y)
>>> y1 is y2
False
```

But this is an implementation detail. The interpreter would be permitted to use a cache to return the same `float` object instead of constructing multiples, and in the `int` case this is what it actually does, at least [for small `int` values in CPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).

```py
>>> x1 = int(x)
>>> x2 = int(x)
>>> x1 is x2
True
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I somewhat got a good understanding of your answer:) 
I would really be grateful if you could explain, if you are free, a little more in detail on the last few lines which you wrote. About that cache.

Comment: If you follow the link to [the other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers), you can find an explanation of how `int` objects are cached in CPython.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Python caches small integer objects, and your example demonstrates that when this happens is not always obvious. As such you should us `id()` to compare identities.

You can find other questions on SO that give more details about this cacheing such as: [What's with the integer cache maintained by the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172182/6144626)